# Sharepoint 2013 Reusable Workflow Unable to send Email to multiple contacts

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I need to create a reusable Workflow, I have 2 Columns

1. News
2. NewsSubscriber

My Task is to send an Email when News:Column Approved then send an Email to the contacts in NewsSubscriber:Email Column (There are multiple contacts in Email Column).I  have followed [this](http://go.limeleap.com/community/bid/292450/Create-a-Workflow-for-Multiple-SharePoint-Forms-Using-SharePoint-Designer) and [this](http://plexhosted.com/billing/knowledgebase/255/How-to-create-a-reusable-workflow-in-SharePoint-Designer-SharePoint-2010.html) articles to create my workflow.I have successfully created them but I am facing two issues

1. Unable to Send Email to multiple contacts (Please Note : It gives me warning when I am setting *To* in Email please see image )[image]

To Portion of my Workflow [image]

2. My Workflow is not sending Email Automatically.

Comment: The warning is not related to what you think, it states that when fetching data from a different list there could be more than 1 item fulfilling your  filtering criteria, in that case the first item returned would be used!

Answer (score 0):

When you select the field to enter data in "To" field of send email, always select `display names(Semicolon delimited)` and make sure the column allows multiple values!

[image]

It will send email to multiple users then.

> Also,the warning is not related to what you think, it states that when
>   fetching data from a different list there could be more than 1 item
>   fulfilling your  filtering criteria, in that case the first item
>   returned would be used!

Comment: Return field as: Option is disabled in my case What should I do??

Comment: What type of column is it? Can you share column setting and the screenshot of return field being disable.

Comment: please see image in **To Portion of my Workflow**  in my question.

Comment: What is the column type of Column named "Email"?

Comment: Single line of text

Comment: why are you using Single line of text? shouldn't it be people type field?

Comment: Actually I am taking Input in Email therefore I kept this field as a string, are not AD Users.

Comment: Oh ok! now I understand, SharePoint won't send emails outside your registered AD! You can try simply giving your yahoo email id in the "To" field and check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30813/discussion-between-baseer-haider-and-taran-goel).

Comment: Is there any other solution to send Email to the outside user Via Sharepoint???

Comment: To do that you need to change farm settings and if I'm not wrong web.config setting as well.